# Why does Mojang write Minecraft in Java

Tags: java, minecraft-modding

Is there any specific reason why Java was the right choice for Minecraft?

Comment: Discussed on minecraft forums and very likely not fit for this site. http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/751674-why-is-minecraft-created-with-java/

Comment: They just chose to use Java, probably because they were more familiar with it than for example C++. It most likely would run a lot better if it was coded in (proper) C++

Comment: @JaakkoLipsanen And that's the point where discussion starts...

Comment: "Because."  It's entirely subjective as to whether it was the _right choice_ or not, too.

Comment: Obviously it's because Mojang spend years learning every single programming language in existence, weighting their syntax, semantics and available solutions, libraries and frameworks. And after all of this he decided that Java was a best language for Minecraft…

Comment: Why does it matter anyway?

Comment: Because Java was developed by Satan. And Mohang are satan worshippers. Source : I'm their cult leader.

Comment: @JacksonGariety The talk of java being slow is mostly outdated; java used to be slow but thats just not true any more. C++ is still theoretically faster but in real world examples java often turns out to be faster http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4516778/when-is-java-faster-than-c-or-when-is-jit-faster-then-precompiled

Comment: @RichardTingle please don't do that. Don't turn it into a who is faster than what. Don't trust benchmarks either. If the C++ developer compiled for a specific target chip instead of just generic x86/x64 instructions, it would be faster. Why? Because precompiled, static, optimized assembly is always going to be faster than on-the-fly generated (dynamic), optimized assembly, if for no other reason than the overhead of the JIT. You're trying to argue that you can toast toast faster by building the toaster first against a prebuilt toaster.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I saw a video from GDC 2012 where Markus "Notch" Persson said that he used Java because it's what he felt most productive in, at least at the time. It was only a passing comment though and note that this video is post-Minecraft, so his reasoning may not have been the same when he started Minecraft.

Source: ["Back to the Garage: The Return of Indie Development"](http://www.gdcvault.com/play/1015646/Back-to-the-Garage-The) from about 14:45 in answer to the question "What Tools or Technology Would You Recommend?"

Comment: Exactly this. Certain languages have drawbacks and advantages, but you write in what you're most comfortable in.

Answer (score 4):

A lot of people hate on Java, but honestly, modern Java is quite good. I mean, sure javac will never be as fast as a C/C++ compiler but if you take an in-depth look on how your Java code gets compiled into what eventually gets read by the JVM, you'll see why it's "slower."

Regardless, Java is a powerful and straight-forward language and I could speculate that he chose it both for the fact that he was comfortable with it and that he recognized that Java has platform-independence. That is, you can write your code (excluding native libraries you may be using) and compile it on that machine and it should be able to run on machines with different architecture, so long as they have the required JDK/JRE installed. And the way that Java handles networking-related tasks makes online(ish) games significantly easier to deal with. It also doesn't require you to explicitly handle all of your memory all of the time, something I find nice. Obviously, some people dislike that and, in all honesty, handling your memory 100% on your own is the "correct" way of doing it, but who does things the correct way these days? We have fast computers, let the garbage collector clean up our mess so we can focus on making fun games instead of the best way to handle dereferenced variables.

Here's some more thoughts, I like the second comment quoting John Carmack: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034458/why-arent-video-games-written-in-java

Comment: Sometimes java can really be faster than c++ because the JIT knows exactly what system its running on and can optimise for just that system whereas a C compiler must target a subset of systems

Comment: @RichardTingle you do have a point, but an experienced C++ developer can run compiler flags that target specific processors, which makes the compiler take full advantage of those ops, just in the same way that a good jit runtime can. So it can't really be "faster", again it's about tuning the language you're writing in.

Comment: The fact that you can't even have functions at ALL in java, proves java is complete and utter garbage.

How it become anymore than an esoteric research language is beyond me.

Comment: @MarcusJ are you allright?
Everything OK there buddy?

Answer (score 1):

That is a question for the "[What If Machine](http://futurama.wikia.com/wiki/What-If_Machine)" from Futurama unless they officialy say it somewhere you can never tell. From what I would say it might have been chosen due to the fact that Java is cross platform and it is very easy to install it on Windows, Mac or Linux.

The second reason; the reason I would choose, is the fact that he must have had previous experience with Java. He said that he had worked for [king.com](http://king.com). Here is the possible explenation. So from what I understand, he simply dislikes C++.

> https://mojang.com/notch/
>
> Hello
>
> My name is Markus Persson, and I'm a programmer. You can call me
>   "Notch". If you want to, you can email me at notch@mojang.com. Be
>   warned that my spam filter eats far too many real emails, though. What
>   I Do
>
> I currently run my own company called Mojang Specifications, where I'm
>   currently developing a game called Minecraft.
>
> I used to work for Jalbum as a programmer. Or developer. Or code guru.
>   We got to pick our own titles. :D
>
> **> Before that, I worked for King.com as a game programmer for 4.5 years.
>   I wrote games like Funny Farm, Luxor, and Carnival Shootout. I mostly
>   did actionscript programming there, but also some java for the game
>   verification code. Recently, I've done some work in C++. It's a
>   powerful language and fun, but the retarded compilation system makes
>   me cry a bit.**
>
> I was one of the founders of a unique mmorpg called Wurm Online. I'm
>   no longer active there. I also make music under the name Markus
>   Alexei. It's electronica, and releases are very far apart.

Comment: He used to write small Flash games for king.com, then decided to take a break to work on some solo projects. He liked Zach Barth’s [Infiniminer](http://www.zachtronics.com/infiniminer/), but Zach had it on the back-burner while he worked on [SpaceChem](http://www.zachtronics.com/spacechem/), so Markus decided to make a his own sandbox game—Lego Group missed the boat even more than Zach. He was using ActionScript and Java at the time, so naturally he wrote the first version of [CaveGame](http://youtu.be/F9t3FREAZ-k) in that. Platform portability was a nice side-benefit. Changing later is hard.